# .Net Controller Action to Receive and Processes a Submitted PDF

Tags: .net, pdf

I have a simple PDF Form with a Submit button that is using the HTTP Address submission method.

How can I create a Controller action to read either the FDF data or the PDF(whole file).

I'm not getting any Form or File data with the Request in my controller action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When submitting this form through a browser, I was not getting any Form Keys, however when submitting it directly from the PDF Editor (Foxit Pro in this case) form data was being passed to the controller.